# Namvaluepair blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry, qml

> ```
>          //android List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
>          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("banker_username", value));
>          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("banker_password", value2));
>           //blackberry 
>          QByteArray postData;
>         postData.append("banker_username="+user);
>         postData.append("banker_password="+pass);
>         QNetworkReply* reply = netManager->post(request,postData);
> ```

it doesnt work in bb like in android, how can i send params via post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example I used for Imgur upload. The rest of the code is [here](http://www.darkenergy.si/anonymous-imgur-authentication-in-blackberry-10/).

```
multiPart->append(imagePart);
QUrl url("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload");
QNetworkRequest req(url);
req.setRawHeader("Authorization",  "Client-ID yourimgurid");
QNetworkReply* ipReply = netManager->post(req, multiPart);
```

Basically you append to QNetworkRequest